# DataTables/jquery .makeEditable plugin/ use previous td content string for editable ajax load GET

Tags: jquery, datatables

Here is a snippet of my script:

```
.makeEditable({
    sUpdateURL : "lib/edit.php?what=" + what + "&action=edit&user=" + authUser,
    sAddURL : "lib/edit.php?what=" + what + "&action=add&user=" + authUser,
    sDeleteURL : "lib/edit.php?what=" + what + "&action=delete&user=" + authUser,
    sAddDeleteToolbarSelector : ".dataTables_length",
    "oAddNewRowFormOptions" : {
        "title" : "Add Machine",
        "width" : 400,
        "height" : 450
    },

    "aoColumns" : [null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,
    {
        tooltip: 'Click to select warehouse',
        loadtext: 'loading...',
        type: 'select',
        onblur: 'cancel',
        submit: 'Ok',
        loadurl: 'lib/ajax.php?do=warehouse',
        loadtype: 'GET',

    }, {

        tooltip: 'Click to select location',
        loadtext: 'loading...',
        type: 'select',
        onblur: 'cancel',
        submit: 'Ok',
    loadurl: 'lib/ajax.php?do=location&wh='+ wh,
        loadtype: 'GET',

    }, null]
});
```

The second editable column needs to have options loaded based on the selection of the first, so I am adding: &wh='+ wh to the loadurl, but I am drawing a blank on how to get the necessary selection (the previous 'td' contents) in that loadurl statement. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Is there any way to get a variable to the 'loadurl' parameter from a td generated by datatables?